# Different action on 8 and 4 characters entered as input in textfield

Tags: java, actionlistener, java-6

I'm using an old java framework (Java 6) .
I have to do a different action on manual input and on scanning input.

The framework gives both as a String, manual (by keyboard) it will be 4 characters long which requires me to do an action with it.
When it is scanned through a usb scanner the String is 8 characters long, not as 1 block but character per character rapidly in succession.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(EventObject arg) {
    if (arg.getSource().equals(txfInput)) {
        if(txfInput.length()==4){
           doAction(txfInput);
        }else if(txfInput.length()==8){
           doOtherAction(txfInput);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that it triggers on the 4th character of the 8 when scanning with a scanner. How can I let it pass the 4th character?

Haven't tested this but I assume this will be an equivalent of my code in Swing.

```
public class Test extends JFrame {
  JTextField text = new JTextField("Press Return", 8);

  public Test() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    text.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       if(text.getText().length()==4){
        do something
       } else if(text.getText().length()==8){
         do something else
       }
      }
   });

  getContentPane().add(text, "Center");
   pack();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
   new Test().setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ActionListener only triggers after receiving Enter I think, and not on a char by char basis? This would mean the text.getText() value will always be 8 chars long for the scanner input.

If not, perhaps it's possible to add a KeyListener to catch the manual input events and check for length=4, and add the ActionListener for the scanner events where you check for length=8?

```
text.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(text.getText().length()==8){
      do something
    }
  }
});


text.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
   }

   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
   }

   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
     if(text.getText().length()==4){
       do something
     }
   }
});
```

Not sure if the scanner would fire those keyTyped events as well though...

Comment: The Swing code was just as a debugable example the actual code triggers on every char entered so it's indeed more like a keylistener and it triggers at 4 characters when the total will be 8 so I fixed it by getting a faster scanner that doesn't trigger the `length == 4`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the variable `txfInput` means in your code. But understood your problem. Seems you can call the method `doAction` with delay and cancel the calling if the length is more than four characters. You can do it like that:

```
private AtomicBoolean doFourCharacters = new AtomicBoolean(true);

public void actionPerformed(EventObject arg) {
    final String txfInput = arg.getSource().toString();
    if (txfInput.length() == 4) {
        doFourCharacters.set(true);
        new Timer().schedule(
                new TimerTask() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                         if (doFourCharacters.get()) {
                             doAction(txfInput);
                         }
                     }
                 }, 500 /* here you should set suitable delay value */);
    } else if(txfInput.length() == 5) {
        doFourCharacters.set(false);
    } else if(txfInput.length() == 8) {
        doOtherAction(txfInput);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer stupidly enough was setting the scanner to scan faster but @AnarAmratanov's answer would probably work too.